# Importing Stencil JS components to a HTML file causing CORS error

Tags: javascript, amazon-cloudfront, stenciljs

I have generated some custom components using Stencil JS, created build files, and deployed those to an s3 bucket, served via Cloudfront as CDN. Now the issue is that when I am referencing the build file to a local HTML file from time to time it is showing CORS error:

```
Access to script at 'https://example.com/assets/my-web-components/my-web-components.esm.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The import is nothing complicated:

```
<script type="module" src="https://example.com/assets/my-web-components/my-web-components.esm.js"></script>
```

If I remove the `type="module"` the script is loading fine, but I am seeing import error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Is there a way to get over this?

Comment: Are you just opening the file in your browser or are you serving it locally and loading from localhost e.g. `http://localhost:8080/index.html`?

Comment: My app is hosted in aws served via cloudfront, but have tried serving locally as well. Though just opening the file might make sense to get that error but I am getting that in a served app